# Worldpay library compatiblity with Newtonsoft 2.0.0.0

Tags: c#, json.net, worldpay

I'm trying to integrate online payment in a existing web application.

I'm using as a payment vendor worldpay which has a git link ([link](https://github.com/Worldpay/worldpay-lib-dotnet))

The problem is that the sdk is built on version 2.0.0.0 of Newtonsoft and in the other web application I'm using version 10.

I've tried to build again the SDK with version 10.0.0.0 but I get a build failure.

I've also tried to use both dll with diferent versions using codeBase but it doesn't seem to work.

Does someone has any ideas how to use this sdk with a greater version of Newtonsoft?

Answer (score 1):

The way we resolved this problem was by renaming worldpay's **Newtonsoft.Json.dll** to **WorldPayNewtonsoft.Json.dll**.

1 Download [worldpay-lib-dotnet-3-5](https://github.com/Worldpay/worldpay-lib-dotnet/tree/master/worldpay-lib-dotnet-3-5) from [worldpay-lib-dotnet](https://github.com/Worldpay/worldpay-lib-dotnet)

2 Open with visual studio [Newtonsoft.Json](https://github.com/Worldpay/worldpay-lib-dotnet/tree/master/worldpay-lib-dotnet-3-5/Newtonsoft.Json) project, rename it to **WorldPayNewtonsoft.Json.dll** (from **Project (right click) -> Properties -> Assembly name**) and build it.

3 Open [Worldpay.Sdk](https://github.com/Worldpay/worldpay-lib-dotnet/tree/master/worldpay-lib-dotnet-3-5/Worldpay.Sdk) project in visual studio and replace the **Newtonsoft.Json** reference with the new one called **WorldPayNewtonsoft.Json.dll** and build **Worldpay.Sdk project**.

4 Take then the new built **Worldpay.Sdk.dll** and **WorldPayNewtonsoft.Json.dll** from bin folder and put them into **your project references** without worrying about Newtonsoft.Json.dll conflicts.

In our case this made it work.

Hope it helps!