# 'JsonConvert' is not declared - but Newtonsoft.Json IS referenced

Tags: vb.net, json.net, visual-studio-2019

I am working on a website project which includes several lines in one of the classes like this:

```
Dim asfPaymentInstalmentRequestJson As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(asfPaymentInstalmentRequest)
```

For some reason the JsonConvert part is underlined red and when I try to build the project I get this error:

```
BC30451 'JsonConvert' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

According to the documentation JsonConvert is part of Newtonsoft.Json, and I have the Nuget package for version 13.0.1 installed. I have this imports statement:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
```

I notice there is also a reference to WorldpayNewtonsoft.Json version 2.0.0.0 so i'm wondering if this could be causing some sort of conflict?

I didn't build this website but i'll need to make changes to it so I need to know how to fix this issue. Any ideas?

The website is built in VB.Net and I am using Visual Studio 2019

UPDATE

I found that there wasn't a Newtonsoft.Json.dll in the bin directory so I copied one in, but then I get errors like:

```
error BC30560: 'JsonPropertyAttribute' is ambiguous in the namespace 'Newtonsoft.Json'
```

and

```
error BC30661: Field or property 'PropertyName' is not found
```

So it seems the two versions of Newtonsoft.Json aren't playing nice with each other. Somehow this is working on our uat site so there must be a way to get these two to work together but I just can't seem to find it.

Comment: Weird... maybe this has something to do with it? https://stackoverflow.com/q/47888523/4294399

Comment: I don't think so. The Worldpay version of NewtonSoft.Json has already been renamed and I still get the error.

Comment: You might want to look at the answer again, it's a lot more involved than just renaming the library.  You will need to make sure that you're not referencing the Worldpay version of Json from your project regardless of the name (you shouldn't need the reference for the Worldpay library to work).

Comment: I think WorldpayNewtonsoft.Json is needed so removing the reference won't work. Strangely it builds for my colleague who seems to have the same configuration, so I don't get why it won't for me.